# how to give alert box while blocking button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am testing some condition using jquery. If the condition fails, the submit button will get blocked. This functionality is working properly. But I also want to show an alert box when the submit button get blocked.
This is my jquery code:

```
var a=parseInt($('#last_bid_price').val());
var b=parseInt($('#bid_amount').val());
var c=parseInt($('#reserved_price').val());

$('#bid_amount').on('keyup blur', function() {

    a=parseInt($('#last_bid_price').val());
    var b=parseInt($('#bid_amount').val());
    var c=parseInt($('#reserved_price').val());

    if(isNaN(a)) {
        a = 0;

        if(b > c)
        {
            $('#save').removeAttr("disabled");

        }
        else
        {
            $('#save').attr("disabled","disabled");

        }

    }

    else if(b > a)
    {

        $('#save').removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    else
    {
        $('#save').attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
});
```

I only need to show an alert box when the button is blocked. Can anyone help me to add that feature in my jquery bcode? I tried lot of things, but I didn't get what I wanted.

Comment: Just add `alert("Some message");` directly before or after you set the disabled attribute?

Comment: in my jquery, where i add that code?.; I tried many ways. Alert should show only if the button is blocked

Comment: _"directly before or after you set the disabled attribute"_ - ie. in your `else` blocks

Comment: am checking two condition, in both condition if button get blocked i need to show alert box, i tried by adding alert box. So can you please tell clearly , in which place i need to add alert box in my code

Comment: I don't know how I can explain more clearly.

Comment: `$('#save').attr("disabled","disabled"); alert("Some message");`

Comment: No , he need to show that alert message on clicking on the disabled button which is not possible.

Comment: @Parvez  _But i want show alert box also when the submit button get block._

Comment: its not working

Comment: @RAHULVP Listen, you have to test your code a little bit before posting a question. The `alert()` function IS working. If it does not show, it is just because you never enter in your `else` block. Test your values with `console.log()` and test more your code. In addition of that, I strongly recommand you to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if am not entering to my else condition, then blocking function also not work, right?. Everything is working perfectly. But i want to show a alert box when button is blocked.